# Logback with logstash encoder, custom ValueMaskSupplier

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I want my logs to appear in JSON format. Hence have used logback-logstash-encoder for logging purposes.

I am able to implement most of my usecases except the masking one.
The description given in https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder#masking lacks examples of how to do custom implementation of ValueMaskSupplier and ValueMasker's

Can anyone points me to some examples which helps me to understand it better.

Also, I have 2 more queries:

1. I am implementing this logstash lib in my spring boot project and all regex patterns to test, against a message will come from configurations i.e application.properties.

in my **application.properties**, configuration looks like:

```
log.masking.maskPattern=(\w+@\w+\.\w+)
```

**Now how could i access it below in ${maskPattern}, as its not able to retrieve value:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="maskingEnabled" source="log.masking.enabled"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="maskPattern" source="log.masking.maskPattern"/>
    <appender name="console_masking" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
                <value>${maskPattern}</value>
                <path>Message/*</path>
            </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
            <providers/>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="console_masking"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

2. My masking usecase says that "value" tag can contains any number of comma seperated regex patterns to be tested against a message. Also it can have a link to a file also, which can contain regex patterns.

Can anyone helps me to understand how can I achieve this usecase as I didn't get any online example to create a custom MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator.

Please help.